# Alert Message in external Cordova Android Plugin?

Tags: java, android, cordova

I there a way to show a message from android java files in cordova? I've tried alert, log.i, console.log, print and System.out.println, but nothing works. By building the app, an error shows up.

for example:

```
log.w("test");
error: no suitable method found for w(String)
```

Only callbackContext works, but sends a success or failed return and the code stops at this point.

EDIT:
System.out hasn't appeared anything, now I try over hours to work with loadUrl but recieve error messages like this one:

```
error: variable mainView might not have been initialized
```

Code:

```
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
public class VideoCapture extends CordovaPlugin {
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

    CordovaWebView mainView;
    mainView.loadUrl("javascript:alert('hello');");
```

How do I implement the webView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `System.out`, it should appear on the logcat

if you want to execute javascript code from java you can use the `loadUrl` method, so you can use javascript `alert` or console.log. Example:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert('hello');");
```

or to run it on the UI Thread

```
cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert('hello');");
    }
});
```

or this to run on main thread

```
cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert('hello');");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank You for answering my question. System.out hasn't appeared anything, now I try over hours to work with loadUrl but recieve error messages like this one:  
  
error: variable mainView might not have been initialized  
  
Code:  
    import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;

    public class VideoCapture extends CordovaPlugin {
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
      
        CordovaWebView mainView;
        mainView.loadUrl("javascript:alert('hello');");

How do I implement the webView?

Comment: oh this looks awkward :(

Comment: As you are using my code on a plugin, you should be able to use this.webView.loadUrl instead of creating your mainView, because CordovaPlugin has a webView

Comment: I receive a warning:   
A WebView method was called on thread 'JavaBridge'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread.   
  
What does it mean?

Comment: It's a warning telling you that the function was called on the different thread, try with my modified answer

Comment: if I use your code, it cannot find a symbol, but when I delete "this." the alert message pops up. On Main Thread the App crashes. But that's not a problem for me. All I was searching for was an alert message, that shows me, if it goes throu the code. Thank You for your help :)

Comment: removed the this. from the answer, I didn't really try. I'm glad that worked